# How to increase the arrow size on oint

Tags: arrows

With my font of choice (for other reasons), the arrow indicating the orientation of the contour appears very small. Is there a way to increase its size, specifically the arrowhead? There is no shaft.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\begin{document}
Evaluate \[\ointctrclockwise_C \frac{z}{2z+3}\,dz,\] where $C$ is the unit circle.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to the absolute minimum. It does not compile here and fore sure, not all packages are needed. You should be more specific on what to increase. The arrow head or the whole thing including it's shaft (and line width)? Are arrows from other fonts a solution? Are you able to use Xe- or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect your suggestions. I would like a solution using this font with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: `mathdesign` defines that integral with `DeclareMathSymbol` (in `mdbch.sty`) so it's just what's defined in the font.  But you could try making your own version by combining the normal integral with a circular arrow if you can find one you prefer.

Comment: If you mean that you can do better arrow than font designer then you can find the file `md-chrmb.pfb` in your system, open it by `fontforge` program, find the character `anticlockwisecontintegraldisplay`, edit this character and generate new `md-chrmb.pfb` for your personal use.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to take a counterclockwise arrow symbol, `\circlearrowleft` from the `amsmath` package, and then scale, rotate, and align it. This produces a nice-looking `\oint` whose circular arrow can be made as large as you like; however, you have to adjust the scaling and aligning parameters correspondingly.

In the following code, you can adjust the integral in several ways. `\rotatefactor` is the amount, in degrees, that the symbol was rotated; and `\scalefactor` indicates how much it was scaled. If you adjust these, you'll have to play with `\raiseamt`, which controls the vertical location of the arrow, and `\leftamt`, which controls its horizontal location.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \circlearrowleft
\usepackage{rotating} % for \rotatebox
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \scalebox

\newcommand{\scalefactor}{1.55}
\newcommand{\rotatefactor}{-73}
\newcommand{\raiseamt}{0.7em}
\newcommand{\leftamt}{-1.22em}

\newcommand{\bigoint}{%
  \raisebox{\raiseamt}{%
    \rotatebox{\rotatefactor}{%
      \scalebox{\scalefactor}{\(\circlearrowleft\)}%
    }%
  }%
\hspace{\leftamt}\int\limits}
```

Then, in your document, the following code

```
\[
  3+\ointctrclockwise_C \frac{z}{2z+3}\,dz
  \quad\mathrm{versus}\quad
  3+\bigoint_C \frac{z}{2z+3}\,dz
\]
```

produces

[image]

If this is too big, too small, etc., just fiddle with the parameters.

Things I don't like about this solution: (1) the arrow itself is kind of thick. Perhaps just replacing the head with a scaled `^` symbol would suffice; such a solution could use the same approach as this one. (2) I feel like the spacing isn't perfect; the fraction is too close to the integral. I guess this is kind of unChartered territory, though.